# Does python has a command/option which can change working directory?

Tags: python

I have a client.py which import moudle from other places. So i want to change work directory using command "python client.py".

Comment: `os.chdir()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')

#use '../' to jump back one folder

import file
```

Code comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)